# Retirar espaços desnecessários em tags html

Tags: html, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Boa tarde, 
é uma questão simples porém estou a algum tempo quebrando a cabeça para resolver.

Toda vez que salvo um arquivo html no sublime 3, ele coloca um espaco vazio, fazendo o form ficar assim : EX:

```
<input type="checkbox " name=" " id=" ">
```

e infelizmente este espaço não deixa que o html seja processado corretamente, e gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso e sabe como resolver. Obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou desinstalar e instalar novamente?

Comment: Não tentei, vou tentar isso!

Comment: Verifique se não é algum plugin que está fazendo isso. Já usei um que ele não reconhecia tags como o <br />, <meta> ou <link>.